# Is there any resource in puppet to create 'cgroup' on linux?

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I need to run following command via puppet.

`sudo /bin/cgcreate -g net_cls:1234567`

Looking for some suggestions to create cgroup in puppet using inbuilt resource if any.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use an exec.

```
exec { 'net_cls_cgroup':
  command => '/bin/cgcreate -g net_cls:1234567',
  creates => '/sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/1234567',
}
```

Be aware that the path of creates could vary depending on the exact opeating system you are using.